# I am trying to find out the model and year of my bicycle, i know it is a giant and has 27.5 in wheels,it has hydraulic disc brakes and hydraulic seat

Tags: identify-this-bike

My giant has hydraulic disc brakes and hydraulic seat. It has 27.5in maxxis 4 bar 60 psi tires. I was told it was carbon fiber . It looks like a mountain bike style with thick tires.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycle Stack Exchange. A photo of the bike would go a long way toward nailing down the model and model year. The presence of the "hydraulic seat," (likely what's called a dropper post, referring to the seat post that can change heights with the activation of a lever located on the handlebars or sometimes at the post itself) is an indication of a newer model (within the last 7 years).

Comment: I second what @Jeff said.  I would add that several photos instead of just one could help. One of the drivetrain, one of the cockpit (handlebar and shifters/brakes), the front suspension, and the overall bike.  A model may be revealed by some of the wording/numbering found on the frame (just like how you identified that it was a Giant). And welcome as well to Bicycle Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thanks guys I'm trying to add a picture now but am having trouble.